# How to translate the localhosts database name and connect remotely in php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a remote server. This code works when I'm directly on the server. (username / pass changed..). The URL is `myuniversity.edu/myfolder`

I think I want to change it to `myuniversity.edu/foo/bar` .. but that doesn't work. So how would I translate the name of the database? My research on google isn't turning up anything helpful. My specific folder shouldn't be a factor as many other students connect with the exact some code.

```
function dbConnect()
{
    $serverName = 'foo\bar';
    $uName = 'un';
    $pWord = '***';
    $db = 'RWS';

    try
    {
       //instantiate a PDO object and set connection properties

       $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$serverName; Database=$db", $uName, $pWord,
       array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

       //return connection object

       return $conn;
    }
   catch (PDOException $e)
   {
       // if connection fails
       die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change **myuniversity.edu/foo/bar** to **myuniversity.edu/server=foo&name=bar**

then change

> $serverName = 'foo\bar'; to
>
> $serverName = $_GET['server']+$_GET['name'];

i seems in your code that folder directing would not give you a variable to be read by php...hope this would give you an idea